# Polymer 1.0 Pagination Implementation

Tags: pagination, polymer, polymer-1.0

We are trying to implement pagination feature for an existing polymer based application. We are currently in polymer version 1.0. Is there any element in polymer 1.0 which can be used to implement pagination. Elements like pagination-input have dependencies of 2.0.

Any pointer to implement this feature in 1.x will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [pagination-input element by cforgeard](https://github.com/cforgeard/pagination-input) has 2.0 dependencies however, a quick look into the code shows that this element could be easy downgraded to Polymer 1. Switching out the class based syntax and adjusting the dependency versions should do the trick.

I don't think there are any other pagination Elements